# SQL Server code works as anonymous block but does not within procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have tried to figure out what the issue is but, unfortunately, without success.

Here is the code in question:

```
DECLARE @_l_Results_Table   TABLE ( Code          nvarchar(32)  ,
                                    Name          nvarchar(64)  ,
                                    Zone          int           ,
                                    Source_Type   nvarchar(16)  ,
                                    Object_Type   nvarchar(16) 
                                  ) ;

INSERT @_l_Results_Table
    SELECT Code  , Name  , Zone  , Source_Type , Object_Type  
      FROM [UWQ].[T_DATA_Object_Sources]
     WHERE CODE = 'AB0045';

SELECT  'Code'                                                       AS Field_Name   , 
        CAST(Code                                       AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  , 
        'Y'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Text'                                                       AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Name'                                                       AS Field_Name   , 
        CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name,'\','\\'),'"','\"')   AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Text'                                                       AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Zone'                                                       AS Field_Name   , 
        CAST(Zone                                       AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Select'                                                     AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Source_Type'                                                AS Field_Name   ,
        CAST(Source_Type                                AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Select'                                                     AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Object_Type'                                                AS Field_Name   ,
        CAST(Object_Type                                AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Select'                                                     AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table ;
```

When I run it within the Management Studio as an anonymous block, it yields the expected result.

When I run a stored procedure having this code, I get the error "*Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure p_DATA_Get_Object_Source_Details, Line 62
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."*.

The only difference between this code and that of the complete procedure is the procedure declaration and setting an OUT parameter (scalar).

### Edit

Here is the code of the complete stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UWQ].[p_DATA_Get_Object_Source_Details] ( 
--CREATE PROCEDURE [UWQ].[p_DATA_Get_Object_Source_Details]   (
                                                @_l_Object_Source_Code   NVARCHAR(64)            ,
                                                @_l_Result_Code         INT             OUTPUT  ,
                                                @_l_Result_Message      NVARCHAR(2000)  OUTPUT )

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @_l_Results_Table   TABLE ( Code          nvarchar(32)  ,
                                    Name          nvarchar(64)  ,
                                    Zone          int           ,
                                    Source_Type   nvarchar(16)  ,
                                    Object_Type   nvarchar(16) 
                                  ) ;

INSERT @_l_Results_Table
    SELECT Code  , Name  , Zone  , Source_Type , Object_Type  
      FROM [UWQ].[T_DATA_Object_Sources]
     WHERE CODE = 'AB0045';

SELECT  'Code'                                                       AS Field_Name   , 
        CAST(Code                                       AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  , 
        'Y'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Text'                                                       AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Name'                                                       AS Field_Name   , 
        CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name,'\','\\'),'"','\"')   AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Text'                                                       AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Zone'                                                       AS Field_Name   , 
        CAST(Zone                                       AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Select'                                                     AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Source_Type'                                                AS Field_Name   ,
        CAST(Source_Type                                AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Select'                                                     AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Object_Type'                                                AS Field_Name   ,
        CAST(Object_Type                                AS NVARCHAR) AS Field_Value  ,
        'N'                                                          AS Protected    ,
        'Select'                                                     AS Datatype     ,
        ''                                                           AS Min_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Max_Value    ,
        ''                                                           AS Step_Size    ,
        '0'                                                          AS Group_ID        FROM @_l_Results_Table ;

SET @_l_Result_Code = 0 ;

Procedure_Completion:

    RETURN ;

END

GO
```

Comment: The procedure code you posted will not parse. It is missing a parenthesis at the end of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange. I missed that in the copy-paste. In my system it compiles without any issue. Fixed now in this post.

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Once I removed all the 3-4,000 extra spaces to this was legible I don't see any issue that would generate the error you are describing. You should be careful though. You have some bad habits in this code. You should ALWAYS specify the columns in an insert statement. And you should ALWAYS specify the size of character data. I have to say I am quite confused by the point of this code though. Most of the data is just repeated and 4 of the columns all have the exact same value. And why the named block for Procedure_Completion?

Comment: @SeanLange, I'll not comment about the 3-4000 extra spaces not about habits. From my perspective (if you would have the chance to see the code in an editor, you even may appreciate its readability). Anyway, what you see is a sort of template, all the parameters that are currently passed as empty strings will eventually have a value. I made some additional tests: If I comment out from the 3rd field of each select (in the union), things do work.

Comment: I can't replicate the error message you are getting at all, so it's hard to help. What is on line 62 of the procedure in your original code? That might give us a clue.

Comment: I added debug prints just before the series of select - union - select -... and another immediately after. The one **before** is printed but the next is not. The issue appears to be starting with the third field of each select of the union. Indeed, I commented out the third till last fields of each select and it works.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error using the code provided. For debugging can you make each select a separate insert instead of a union (with a print/select after each)? It may help isolate where the issue is.

Comment: @SeanLange, already tried that. I commented out all but the very first select and still get error unless I also comment out from the third to the last field of the select (when I select only the first two fields it works) and it works. Again, the issue appears to be related to having more than two fields in the select.

Comment: Bad habits make for bad code.  Since you are having a problem with the insert portion, trying fixing some of your bad habits and see if the code clears up.  I'd start by adding column names to the insert statement.  In addition, using NVARCHAR without specifying the length can cause a lot of data quality headaches for you.  http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2012/03/declaring-varchar-without-length.html .

Comment: @WesH, First, added the list of fields in the Insert (not really needed, but still...). Second, after more than 30 years of programming in over 20 different languages and most operating systems (including some languages and systems you most probably never heard of), I live quite OK with my habits. Let's please focus on the issue, shall we?

Comment: @WesH by the way, if you read the complete question you will find out that the code DOES work as an anonymous block, so it would be fair to assume that there is a small probability that the issue might not be with the code.

Comment: Can you post some sample data for the T_DATA_Object_Sources (and datatypes) that can replicate the issue? I understand your frustration but sometimes the error is because of implicit conversion when the length isn't specified for varchars. If anybody could recreate this issue we can help figure out a solution but we can't fix a bug we can't reproduce.

Comment: @FDavidov using nvarchar without a length will limit it to 30 characters.  Since you explicitly defined your Code and Name columns as larger than that, I assume that there is a problem with the code caused by a bad habit, even if it is not the problem you're trying to solve now.

Comment: I execute your SP and there is no issue. Can you show your code using this SP?

Comment: I found the issue thanks to @TriV who requested to see the code that invokes the SP: (1) The code block that invokes the SP gets the result into a temporary table. (2) The initial version of the SP returned a table with only two columns. (3) Once the procedure worked successfully, I added the remaining 6 columns to the result **BUT** forgot to do the same to the temporary table that receives the result. That explains why any combination of two parameters worked regardless of which parameters I selected, but as soon as I added a third it stopped working. Thanks to all for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact that the anonymous block that I used to test the SP was not updated once I change from two returned columns to 8 (as actually needed).

After adapting the temporary table that receives the result within the anonymous block, all worked cleanly.

Thanks to all those who cared to invest efforts assisting, specially TriV who asked the question that brought to my attention the invocation of the SP.